# Setting up an agent authentification with Pingaccess

Tags: pingaccess

I have a CentOS VM with an ready installed Pingaccess Server Testenvironment with access to the Pingaccess Admin UI.
Now I would need to set up an Agent-Authentification on the system but sadly have no experience configuring Pingaccess sofar. I also find it dificult to find documentation to complete my task.

I would appreciate any hints and pointers in right direction or information on how this kind of setup can be configured and what else I might need? Is it even possible to set it up in a local VM?

**Here a slightly more detailed description of the scenario:**
An application that itself is not able to use a corresponding protocol (Oauth, SAML2, ...) (e.g. a small PHP script or something similar) that cannot do anything other than output a user name that it reads from the HTTP headers.

Set up an Agent that extends the header attributes and e.g. something like Header-UserName. The application can then access the web server variables and use these values without having to worry about how the authentication works. The agent, on the other hand, can do the protocols and handle authentication via the server (here PingAccess).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is PingAccess actually configured? That is, is it connected to an OAuth AS/OIDC OP?

Comment: Pingaccess is installed in a standalone VM running CentOS.

It hasn't been configured/connected for/to an OAuth AS/OIDC OP. 
How can this configuration be made? Is there manual on that topic?

Comment: you need to configure it for a token provider. Deciding the proper one (PingFederte, Azure, ADFS, etc.) is a bigger architectural discussion than is appropriate for here. I would suggest contacting your Ping account team for assistance.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. I have Pingfederate installed on the same machine. Maybe I can figure it out. The Ping support is a bit ...well, I tried with them also and the page with the documentation is offline.